# Selenium unable to locate button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

I am trying to click a button on a website in Python using Selenium. The html looks like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-lg primary-light-blue-btn" onclick="createReport()">Create report</a>
```

I have tried using:

```
l = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-default btn-lg primary-light-blue-btn']")
```

But I get the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='btn btn-default btn-lg primary-light-blue-btn']"}
```

I have also tried other things, but it just won't find the button. E.g.:

```
l = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Create report']")
```

I have also tried introducing a wait, but that does not help, e.g.:

```
l = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Create report']")))
```

Comment: That is an `<a>` element, not a `<button>` element.  Why are you looking for a `<button>` element?

Comment: Oh I see. The website shows it as a clickable button for users, but when I inspect the html code, then all I see is what I wrote there. Perhaps I didn’t find the right html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the given HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-lg primary-light-blue-btn" onclick="createReport()">Create report</a>
```

The element is a `<a>` tag.

---

### Solution

To click on the element with text as ***Create report*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *link_text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Create report").click()
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-default.btn-lg.primary-light-blue-btn[onclick^='createReport']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-lg primary-light-blue-btn' and starts-with(@onclick, 'createReport')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Create report"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-default.btn-lg.primary-light-blue-btn[onclick^='createReport']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-lg primary-light-blue-btn' and starts-with(@onclick, 'createReport')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 2):

change the tag `//button` to `//a`:

```py
l = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-lg primary-light-blue-btn']")
```